# Torment of Unbelievers vs those who take the Mark of the Beast

Tags: hell

Revelation 11:10-11

> 10 The same shall drink of the wine of the wrath of God, which is poured out without mixture into the cup of his indignation; and he shall be tormented with fire and brimstone in the presence of the holy angels, and in the presence of the Lamb:
>   11 And the smoke of their torment ascendeth up for ever and ever: and they have no rest day nor night, who worship the beast and his image, and whosoever receiveth the mark of his name.

Questions:

1) Is this torment in Hell, or *while* they are alive?

Since it's "for ever and ever", I'm inclined to believe it's in Hell.

2) While the Holy Angels + God is watching, are the Saints not watching?

3) If it's in Hell, are unbelievers (who did not receive the mark of the beast) treated differently from those who did receive the mark of the beast?

4) Any additional insights on this vs being thrown into the lake of fire is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Hell is just eternal separation from God. The torment will be from those  who have denied Jesus. But the day will come when God will put it onto everyones heart that he is real , it will be too late to repent and this is where the nashing and grinding of teeth will be